# Keras - Adding a math operation between layers

Tags: keras

For my research, I need to perform a math operation between 2 dense layers. that is, for example, take the output vector, power it by 2, and than pass it to next layer.
I tried to use keras API , but that did not work. for example:

```
inputOredData = Input(shape=(100,),name='pred')
powerOut = K.square (inputOredData )
prediction = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(powerOut )
```

I get :

```
You tried to call layer "dense_453". This layer has no information about its expected input shape, and thus cannot be built. You can build it manually via: `layer.build(batch_input_shape)`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own layer such as https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Then, for your purpose you can define the call() methods as follows:

```
def call(self, x, mask=None):
    return K.square(x)
```